# Tikzpicture: A plot isn't where it should be

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I have been trying to add a plot using Tikzpicture, but it does not locate well in the graph. Here is my code:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw[step=1, gray, dashed, very thin] (-0.2,-0.2) grid (2.2,2.2); 
\draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (2.2,0) node[right] {$X_1$}; 
\foreach \x/\xtext in {1/, 2} 
\draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north,fill=white]     {$\xtext$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.2) -- (0,2.2) node[above] {$X_2$};
\foreach \y/\ytext in {1, 2} 
\draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-4pt,\y cm) node[anchor=north,fill=white] {$\ytext$};
\draw[blue, dashed, thick] (1/3,1/3) -- (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[blue, dashed, thick, domain=1/3:1] plot (\x, {1-0.5*(\x)+sqrt((\x)(1-0.75*(\x)))});
\draw[blue, dashed, thick] (5/3,5/3) -- (2,2) -- (1,2);
\draw[dashed,very thin] (0,0) -- (2,2);
\draw[red, fill=red, opacity=0.2] (3/7,1/7) -- ($(0,1)+sqrt(14)*(0,3/14)$) -- ($(0,1)-sqrt(14)*(0,3/14)$) -- cycle;
\draw[red, fill=red, opacity=0.2] (3/7,1/7) -- ($(1,0)+sqrt(14)*(1/7,0)$) -- ($(1,0)-sqrt(14)*(1/7,0)$) -- cycle;
\draw[red, fill=red, opacity=0.2] (11/7,13/7) -- ($(2,1)-sqrt(14)*(0,3/14)$) -- ($(2,1)+sqrt(14)*(0,3/14)$) -- cycle;
\draw[red, fill=red, opacity=0.2] (11/7,13/7) -- ($(1,2)-sqrt(14)*(1/7,0)$) -- ($(1,2)+sqrt(14)*(1/7,0)$) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

And the result is

[image]

All the other parts are okay, but the graph y=1-x/2-sqrt(x(1-3x/4)) isn't where it should be. Obviously it must pass (1/3,1/3) and (1,0) (so make a closed loop with the other two straight lines) but it's way above from its correct location. Furthermore, it is not a straight line but a curve but the result looks like a straight line...

I would really appreciate if you help me out with this trouble!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet compilable ...

Comment: I've just added the packages I used and there was no problem in complying the above code. If it is still not compliable, please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. The only point is the multiplication `*` between `{1-0.5*(\x)+sqrt((\x)` and `(1-0.75*(\x)))});` that you forgot. You have also put `+` instead of `-` in the formulation.

Here is your code and the corresponding plot:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw[step=1, gray, dashed, very thin] (-0.2,-0.2) grid (2.2,2.2); 
\draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (2.2,0) node[right] {$X_1$}; 
\foreach \x/\xtext in {1/, 2} 
\draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north,fill=white]     {$\xtext$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.2) -- (0,2.2) node[above] {$X_2$};
\foreach \y/\ytext in {1, 2} 
\draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-4pt,\y cm) node[anchor=north,fill=white] {$\ytext$};
\draw[blue, dashed, thick] (1/3,1/3) -- (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[blue, dashed, thick, domain=1/3:1] plot (\x, {1-(0.5)*(\x)-sqrt((\x)*(1-(0.75)*(\x)))});
\draw[blue, dashed, thick] (5/3,5/3) -- (2,2) -- (1,2);
\draw[dashed,very thin] (0,0) -- (2,2);
\draw[red, fill=red, opacity=0.2] (3/7,1/7) -- ($(0,1)+sqrt(14)*(0,3/14)$) -- ($(0,1)-sqrt(14)*(0,3/14)$) -- cycle;
\draw[red, fill=red, opacity=0.2] (3/7,1/7) -- ($(1,0)+sqrt(14)*(1/7,0)$) -- ($(1,0)-sqrt(14)*(1/7,0)$) -- cycle;
\draw[red, fill=red, opacity=0.2] (11/7,13/7) -- ($(2,1)-sqrt(14)*(0,3/14)$) -- ($(2,1)+sqrt(14)*(0,3/14)$) -- cycle;
\draw[red, fill=red, opacity=0.2] (11/7,13/7) -- ($(1,2)-sqrt(14)*(1/7,0)$) -- ($(1,2)+sqrt(14)*(1/7,0)$) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**edit:** i wrongly down wrote function formula ... instead `+` before square root it has to be `-`. corrected now:

i guess that you like to obtain something like this (but i'm not sure)

[image]

i rewrote your function and simplify rest of your code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw[step=1, gray, dashed, very thin] (0,0) grid (2.1,2.1);
\draw[->] (-1pt,0) -- (2.1,0) node[right] {$X_1$};
\draw[->] (0,-1pt) -- (0,2.1) node[above] {$X_2$};
\foreach \i in {0, 1, 2}
{
\draw (\i,1pt) -- ++ (0,-2pt) node[below,font=\footnotesize] {$\i$};
\draw (1pt,\i) -- ++ (-2pt,0) node[left ,font=\footnotesize] {$\i$};
}
\draw[blue, dashed, thick] (1/3,1/3) -- (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[blue, dashed, thick, domain=1/3:1] plot (\x, {1-0.5*\x-sqrt(\x-0.75*\x*\x)});
\draw[blue, dashed, thick] (5/3,5/3) -- (2,2) -- (1,2);
\draw[dashed,very thin] (0,0) -- (2,2);

\draw[red, fill=red, opacity=0.2]
    ($(0,1)-sqrt(14)*(0,3/14)$) -- ($(0,1)+sqrt(14)*(0,3/14)$) --
    ($(1,0)-sqrt(14)*(1/7, 0)$) -- ($(1,0)+sqrt(14)*(1/7, 0)$) -- cycle;
\draw[red, fill=red, opacity=0.2]
    ($(2,1)-sqrt(14)*(0,3/14)$) -- ($(2,1)+sqrt(14)*(0,3/14)$) --
    ($(1,2)-sqrt(14)*(1/7, 0)$) -- ($(1,2)+sqrt(14)*(1/7, 0)$) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```